# How to load the Keras model?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

Hi i am trying to load the keras model which was created in Keras: 2.2.4 version and i am trying to load in below specified version.

- ubuntu : 18.04
- python : 3.6.9
- tensorflow version : 1.13.1
- Keras version : 2.3.1

I tried to load the model as below mentioned .

```
import tensorflow as tf

classifierLoad = tf.keras.models.load_model('w.hdf5')
```

while Loading it showing error like this.

> > /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:526: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
> >       _np_qint8 = np.dtype([("qint8", np.int8, 1)])
> >     /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:527: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
> >       _np_quint8 = np.dtype([("quint8", np.uint8, 1)])
> >     /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:528: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
> >       _np_qint16 = np.dtype([("qint16", np.int16, 1)])
> >     /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:529: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
> >       _np_quint16 = np.dtype([("quint16", np.uint16, 1)])
> >     /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:530: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
> >       _np_qint32 = np.dtype([("qint32", np.int32, 1)])
> >     /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:535: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
> >       np_resource = np.dtype([("resource", np.ubyte, 1)])
> >     WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/resource_variable_ops.py:435: colocate_with (from tensorflow.python.framework.ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
> >     Instructions for updating:
> >     Colocations handled automatically by placer.
> >     2020-02-20 18:17:45.291135: W tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:98] Failed to find bogomips in /proc/cpuinfo; cannot determine CPU frequency
> >     2020-02-20 18:17:45.292283: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:161] XLA service 0x27584260 executing computations on platform Host. Devices:
> >     2020-02-20 18:17:45.292367: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168]   StreamExecutor device (0): , 
> >     2020-02-20 18:17:45.438308: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:965] ARM64 does not support NUMA - returning NUMA node zero
> >     2020-02-20 18:17:45.438696: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:161] XLA service 0x237da820 executing computations on platform CUDA. Devices:
> >     2020-02-20 18:17:45.438755: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168]   StreamExecutor device (0): NVIDIA Tegra X1, Compute Capability 5.3
> >     2020-02-20 18:17:45.439077: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1433] Found device 0 with properties: 
> >     name: NVIDIA Tegra X1 major: 5 minor: 3 memoryClockRate(GHz): 0.9216
> >     pciBusID: 0000:00:00.0
> >     totalMemory: 3.87GiB freeMemory: 569.37MiB
> >     2020-02-20 18:17:45.439136: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1512] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
> >     2020-02-20 18:17:50.292455: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:984] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
> >     2020-02-20 18:17:50.295363: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:990]      0 
> >     2020-02-20 18:17:50.295391: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1003] 0:   N 
> >     2020-02-20 18:17:50.295579: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1115] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 105 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: NVIDIA Tegra X1, pci bus id: 0000:00:00.0, compute capability: 5.3)
> >     Traceback (most recent call last):
> >       File "conversion_keras_to_trt.py", line 32, in 
> >         model = load_model(model_fname, custom_objects={'Adam': lambda **kwargs: hvd.DistributedOptimizer(keras.optimizers.Adam(**kwargs))}
> >       File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/saving.py", line 249, in load_model
> >         optimizer_config, custom_objects=custom_objects)
> >       File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizers.py", line 838, in deserialize
> >         printable_module_name='optimizer')
> >       File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/generic_utils.py", line 194, in deserialize_keras_object
> >         return cls.from_config(cls_config)
> >       File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizers.py", line 159, in from_config
> >         return cls(**config)
> >       File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizers.py", line 471, in **init**
> >         super(Adam, self).**init**(**kwargs)
> >       File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizers.py", line 68, in **init**
> >         'passed to optimizer: ' + str(k))
> >     TypeError: Unexpected keyword argument passed to optimizer: name

Any suggestion

Comment: Can you show us the model definition and how you saved it please ?

Comment: thanks for reply----this is how i am saving as checkpoint--checkpoint=ModelCheckpoint(args.model_save_location+'weights.{epoch:02d}-{val_loss:.2f}.hdf5',monitor='val_loss',verbose=0,save_best_only=False,save_weights_only=False,period=1)

Comment: And your model creation ?

Comment: model script :https://drive.google.com/open?id=1vShENNeFBXZ2qDgXv27xTEv4lhMQxZVp

Comment: train script : https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Z66ASQseLdC55bMMa5JE_yeKRrljgtSG

Comment: thanks for you interest @Thibault Bacqueyrisses I have founded a way to load the model, i think its not a correct method, what i did is, I started the training on keras 2.3.1 version and tensorflow 1.14.1 its loading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue comes from the fact that your are mixing plain `keras` and `tensorflow.keras` versions.

They are not compatible. In the future, if you want to train a model, ensure that you train the model in, say, `tensorflow.keras` and then you load from `tensorflow.keras` when you test.

Comment: ya I understood ! Thanks for explanation!@Timbus Calin

Answer (score 0):

I have founded a way to load the model, i think its not a correct method but, what i did is, I started the training on keras 2.3.1 version and tensorflow 1.14.1 version the model is loading.